# Selenium VBA chrome

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome

I have read all the former posts to find the solution but I am still struggling with Selenium for VBA.

I would like to click on a button called "telecharger la page". The HTML code is below :

```
<tbody class="template-list">
<tr id=":y" class="goog-container">
<td>
<i class="icon foundicon-down-arrow pointer download-button general" title="Télécharger la table">
</i>
```

I have tried with this VBA code but it does not work...

```
bot.FindElementsByXPath("//tr[@id=':y']").Click.FindElementsByTag("Télécharger la table").Click
```

Could somebody help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//tr[@id=':y']//i[@title='Télécharger la table']
```

[image]
And you code should be

```
bot.FindElementByXpath("//tr[@id=':y']//i[@title='Télécharger la table']").click
```

Comment: Make sure you use `FindElementByXpath` not `FindElementsByXpath`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are finding an element in another element. That can be achieved using xpath only. Try using below xpath:

```
bot.FindElementsByXPath("//tr[@id=':y']/i").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the elelemtn you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `FindElementByCss`:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("tr.goog-container[id$='y']>td>i.icon.foundicon-down-arrow.pointer.download-button.general[title='Télécharger la table']").Click
  ```
- Using `FindElementByXPath`:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//tr[@class='goog-container' and contains(@id, 'y')]/td/i[@class='icon foundicon-down-arrow pointer download-button general' and @title='Télécharger la table']").Click
  ```